# Access and Linked Tables to SQL Server - edit data in layout view results in transaction and locked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, transactions, linked-tables

I am using Access 2013 and Sql Server 2012.  I have upsized the access application to Sql Server using linked tables.  I have an Access query (not on SQL server) that provides a result from about 4 tables.  I then have this displayed in a bound layout/table view where each row corresponds to a row from the result query.

In the layout view, the user can edit the data in any row.  Once the user does an edit, apparently Access opens a transaction and keeps it open.  As long as the user is in the editable layout view,  the tables that were part of the query are locked.   If another user on a different computer is using Access, then they are unable to edit any of the tables (through any method, not just the same layout view).   The 2nd user will get a 30 second pause in their application, and then finally will get error...

```
ODBC-update on a linked table 'TableName' failed.
[Microsoft][ODBC Sql Server DRiver]Query timeout expired (#0)
```

Once the first user exits the layout view, then all is opened up again for other users to edit.

Is there any way to control the transaction?  Maybe just have it update the one row, and then release the transaction.

May have to change the data source for the layout view to be a SQL Server Sproc or View and not allow edits in the table. Instead, if the user wants to change something in a row, then click to bring up an edit form.  Looking for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few possible solutions.

One solution is to open the form in question with a where clause to ONLY thus open the one row, not many rows.

The above is only practical suggestion if the form in question is NOT a continues form.

So you go:

```
strInvoice = inputbox("What invoice to work on")

docmd.Openform "frmInvoice",,,"[invoiceNum] = " & strInvoice
```

So limiting the form to the one row will fix this assuming there is an index on the invoice column. Also such a design tends to be more user friendly. I explain this important search concept here:

http://www.kallal.ca/Search/index.html

Another way to fix this issue is to FORCE fill the form with all records (this is really a bad idea from a performance point of view, and even without SQL server launching a form WITHOUT ANY kind of where clause as I show above is a bad idea from a user point of view, and also from a performance point of view)..

The reason why the table lock often occurs is the form starts pulling data from SQL server but then Access says HEY WAIT I have enough data – but the queries that started on SQL server already fired off some table locks and ASSUMED that all rows would be returned to the client (so the client halting the flow of records is what really causes your locks). What you can do to prevent this issue is thus execute a move last to pull all records, and thus that will eliminate (release) the table locks.

So in the forms on-load event, you can go:

```
me.recordset.MoveLast
me.recordset.MoveFirst
```

As noted the problem here is that pulling all records into a form is a VERY bad design in the first place.

Last by not least:

Another way to eliminate the table lock is to build the query as a view SQL server side and include the NOLOCK hint. You then setup a link to the view, and based the form NOT on a local query, but that of the view. Since the view has a NOLOCK hint, then you don’t need the movelast/movefirst suggestion as per above.

So out of the several solutions here, opening the form to ONE record is really the recommended solution. I mean when you walk up to an instant teller machine, it does not download EVERY account and THEN ask you what account to work on. When you use a search engine such as google, then it does not download the WHOLE internet and THEN ask you what to search for. Even an old lady at the bus stop can figure this out, let alone someone writing software!

So when you design + build a form in Access, it makes VERY little sense to download all records from the table into the form and THEN let the user search. So the user needs to be prompted for what to work on BEFORE the form is loaded, and if you use a where clause when opening the form EVEN if the form is bound to a large linked table to SQL server ONLY the record(s) that match the where clause will be pulled down into that form.

If you don’t use the where clause, then as noted, the locking issue will rear its ugly head.

As a temp fix, try the movelast/movefirst in the forms on-load, as that should fix the locking issue. However for longer term, I would suggest using a where clause, or consider the view idea.

Note that if you have ANY combo box based on any of the 4 tables, then AGAIN will you find locking issues since the combo box will request the data (and SQL server places a table lock during that request). And AGAIN Access will THEN tell sql server to please stop loading up the combo box since all rows are NOT yet required (but too late, as the table lock has occurred).

So if you have ANY combo box in that form based on any of the tables used, then again you find table locks occur. In these cases, I would again suggest basing the combo boxes on either pass-through quires with the NO LOCK hint, or on views with again the no-lock hint.

So check the  form for any combo box based on any of those tables – they will cause table locks also.

Comment: very nice info.  Considered doing the View, but then you lose the editing capability in the grid since it does not know where/what tables to update (since the data comes from 4 tables).   The data is filtered to a small set, so for quick fix, may use the MoveLast, but may run into the issue with the combos.   May refactor them to use passthru NOLOCK queries.  Great info on why this occurs.  I was figuring it was a transaction, didn't quite understand how access could lock for all other apps.  Ideally, will probably change to readonly grid/Sql View NOLOCK, and then option to single edit a row.

Comment: A view should be updatable and allow you to edit the rows. Certainly many quires that involve multiple tables are often not updatable, but a view based on more then one table will be more or less be updatable like they are in Access.  However, I much agree that creating a continues form with a "edit" button to launch a detail form to edit the one record is a good suggestion/choice on your part.

Comment: In my experience so far, but admit not a lot in this area, that a SQL Server View that just returns back to Access, that it appears that Access does not how to update this since it has no idea of where the values came from.  The View in SQL server hides all of this stuff.  Now, if a query is created in Access, then it has some internal knowledge of the tables and where the columns come from, so is able to handle the update.   Is this what you understand, or have you actually seen where you can have an updateable view from a SQL View?   thx again for your input

Comment: Access does not have to know - it only sees one row of data and sends it back to SQL server (really the same thing a form does in Access when based on a local query of several tables). The fact that the query is based on more than on table is not a problem for Access. And SQL server being an commercial database system handles this issue with ease. It not access that “sends out” the data to the multiple tables when you link to that view. Access thinks this is a single table and row of data. Access will have no idea that the view really is a query that based on several tables.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and expertise.  How does it send it back to SQL.  Do I have to create pre-defined sproc or something?  I do have a lot of experience with SQL Server, so just not understanding how Access can send back the values to SQL.  Generally done through update/insert statements, but if it does not know which tables the columns came from, then not sure how it would know which ones to update.

Comment: It not the access form that splits out the data to multiple tables when a form is bound to a query. Access forms can ONLY be based on ONE ROW. The access form simply says take this row of data and sends it back to the data engine. That data engine is the “thing” that figures out that the row just passed back is based on multiple tables (not the access form – it can ONLY write out one row).

Comment: If that row is based on several tables then the form has no idea that is the case. So yes, based on a form on an Access query of several tables, or a SQL view that that is several tables’ amounts to the same thing. So basing a form on a built in data engine (JET/ACE) or basing the form on a query from SQL server that is several tables is the SAME THING. The Access form has zero knowledge about the multiple tables and a form can ONLY read a row, and save a row (nothing more, nothing less).

Comment: So the form when based on a Access query, or a SQL query can ONLY write out ONE row. it is the data engine that knows the query is based on several tables. So in both cases (local ACE data engine or SQL server) Access can only say please write out this ONE row of data. It is the data engine that knows the row of data was based on several tables. So the access form simply says (sends) that one row of data back to the data engine and says please save the row. It not the Access form that figures this out - the data engine does.